# Laravel 7 pass through relationship and access final table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hi i have these 4 tables: users, dishes, dish_order, orders.

**users**: some fields no foreign key

**dishes**

- id
- name
- desc
- price
- visible
- type
- user_id

**dish_order**

- id
- dish_id
- order_id

**orders**: some fields no foreign key

These are the models: User, Dish, Order.

*User:*

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'password',
    'company_name',
    'address',
    'vat',
    'phone_number',
    'opening_info',
    'website',
    'vote_average'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];

public function dishes() {
    return $this -> hasMany(Dish::class);
}

public function typologies() {
    return $this -> belongsToMany(Typology::class);
}
}
```

*Dish:*

```
class Dish extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'desc',
    'price',
    'visible',
    'type',
];

public function user() {
    return $this -> belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function orders() {
    return $this -> belongsToMany(Order::class);
}
}
```

*Order:*

```
class Order extends Model
{

protected $fillable = [
    'code',
    'customer_name',
    'customer_address',
    'customer_phone',
    'date',
    'status',
    'total_price',
];


public function dishes() {
    return $this -> belongsToMany(Dish::class);
}
}
```

Now in the Controller i need to find all orders related to the user (for example with ID 18).
I tried this and it's work but in this case i lose all dishes related to the order.

```
$loggedUserId = Auth::user() -> id;
$orders = DB::table('users')
          -> join('dishes', 'users.id', '=', 'dishes.user_id')
          -> join('dish_order', 'dishes.id', '=', 'dish_order.dish_id')
          -> join('orders', 'orders.id', '=', 'dish_order.order_id')
          -> select('orders.*', DB::raw('COUNT(dishes.id) as dishes'))
          -> groupBy('orders.id')
          -> where('user_id', $loggedUserId)
          -> get();
```

Result: Array/Collection of orders and each order should have an array inside with list of dishes related to the order. If it's possibile, how can i do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why use querybuilder when you have Eloquent models?

Comment: Post your code directly.  Not use any 3rd party no-paste tool to view your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have eloquent relationship in place in your models so you can utilize those relationships.

```
$orders = Order::whereHas('dishes', function($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', auth()->id());
    })
    ->with(['dishes' => function($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', auth()->id());
    }])
    ->get();
```

The first part `whereHas(...)` will get only the orders that the logged in user has dishes.
The second part `with(...)` will get only the dishes belonging to the logged in user.

Then you can iterate orders and dishes

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
    $order->dishes;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it's work but in my blade files show me all orders in my database not just the orders related to the logged user can i filter the results of $orders in the controller ?

Comment: that's strange, the first part of the query is where it filters only the orders that has dishes from the logged in user.